# VueJs v-for loop not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im trying to make a form where you have buttons to add children inputs but after adding one child the button no longer works and it returns to error in the cole as to why but if i output the data it looks like it is being adding just the DOM isn't being updated with the new input box

```
var default_item = {
  value: 0,
  reps: 0,
  sets: 0
}

var deafult_exercise = {
    exercise_name: '',
    item_data: [default_item]
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    log_data: [
        {
        log_name: 'log #1',
        log_day: 1,
        exercise_data: [
            {
            exercise_name: 'exercise #1',
            item_data: [
                {
                value: 50,
                reps: 5,
                sets: 5
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addLog: function(){
      this.log_data.push({log_name: '', log_day:0, exercise_data: deafult_exercise});
    },
    addExercise: function(index_id) {
    this.log_data[index_id].exercise_data.push(deafult_exercise);
    },
    addItem: function(index_id, log_id) {
    this.log_data[log_id].exercise_data[index_id].item_data.push(default_item);
    }
  }
})
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/renlok/5mpace1q/3/

Comment: It might be because you are pushing the same object every time . Try pushing Object.assign({}, default_item)

Comment: Yeah updated your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5mpace1q/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are pushing the same items and referencing the same items so essentially you are only ever adding 1 item

You need to use

```
Object.assign({}, default_item)
```

To use new instances of the items see updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5mpace1q/4/